# Create .Net Excel::Application in c++/cli

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2012

I want to create an excel file inside of my C++ project, I would use C# but because of other restraints I have to use C++.

When I go to create a new application like this:

```
#define excel Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel
excel::Application^ exlFile = gcnew excel::Application;
```

it underlines `excel::Application` in red and say:

```
Cannot create an object of a CLI interface class
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there no way to create a full application inside of C++/cli? If I am doing something wrong will you please let me know? If you need more information please let me know.

Using VS 2012

```
#using <Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Excel::Application^ xl = gcnew Excel::ApplicationClass()` instead.